# How to auto auto_detect_line_endings in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, line-endings

I am trying to upload the data of a csv file into my database using laravel.
The code works fine with a file, which line endings are "\t".
Now, I have to upload a file, of which I do not know the line ending type.
**Therfore, I would like to use `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);`, which does not work.**
**The controller function**

```
public function uploadExcel()
{
    DB::table('members')->delete();

    $filename = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();

    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    $count = 0;
    while (($emapDataUnescaped = fgetcsv($file, 10000)) !== FALSE) {
        $emapData = self::addslashes_recursive($emapDataUnescaped);
        $count++;

        if($count>1) {
            DB::statement("INSERT INTO `members` (
                member_title,
                member_first_name,
                member_name_affix,
                member_last_name,
                member_private_address,
                member_private_zip_code,
                member_private_location,
                member_private_phone,
                member_private_mobile,
                member_private_fax,
                member_private_mail,
                member_business_position,
                member_business_name,
                member_business_address,
                member_business_zip_code,
                member_business_location,
                member_business_area_code,
                member_business_phone,
                member_business_fax,
                member_business_mobile,
                member_business_mail,
                member_join_date,
                extra
            ) VALUES (
                '$emapData[0]',
                '$emapData[1]',
                '$emapData[2]',
                '$emapData[3]',
                '$emapData[4]',
                '$emapData[5]',
                '$emapData[6]',
                '$emapData[7]',
                '$emapData[8]',
                '$emapData[9]',
                '$emapData[10]',
                '$emapData[11]',
                '$emapData[12]',
                '$emapData[13]',
                '$emapData[14]',
                '$emapData[15]',
                '$emapData[16]',
                '$emapData[17]',
                '$emapData[18]',
                '$emapData[19]',
                '$emapData[20]',
                '$emapData[21]',
                '$emapData[22]'
            )");
        }
    }
    return redirect('index');
}
```

**The project is hosted on a shared hosting environment**, in case that makes a difference.
Is there anyway I can enable auto_detect_line_endings in laravel? Or is there another way to detect the line ending type before processing the file?
I am really new to laravel and would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: \t is not standard line-ending character. That's why it can't be recognised by fgetcsv.

Comment: I think you are talking about csv, not an excel file. If it is this package is the best choice http://csv.thephpleague.com

Comment: I did not know that there is a difference! You are correct, I am talking about an .csv file!

Comment: @kringeltorte, I used this http://csv.thephpleague.com in my projects.

Comment: fyi,  this is nothing to do with the Laravel framework. This is PHP file handling.

Answer (score 0):

> **fyi, this is nothing to do with the Laravel framework. This is PHP file handling.**

Well, you could, if you want to. The following are libraries built to address issues around handling CSV and Excel files.

- **[wilgucki/csv:](https://packagist.org/packages/wilgucki/csv)** Laravel 5 package for writing and reading CSV files.
- **[maatwebsite/excel:](https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel)** An eloquent way of importing and exporting Excel and CSV in Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 with the power of PHPExcel